# Crystal reports doesn't show text

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'm working in crystal reports.

When I open the invoice and run it, it doesn't show some of my variable text spaces.

But when I browse data of the string, it shows:

```
     Type: String
     Length: 12

     Debiteur nr.
```

The SQL code is:

```
    select {Report name.InvCustLangCode} 
        case "NL" : "Debiteur nr."
        case "UK" : "Debtor nr." 
        case "DE" : "Debitor nr." 
        default: "Debiteur"
```

Any help as to why it doesn't show my text in its frame would be nice.

Comment: Are you sure the data table used is proper?

Comment: im pretty sure about that. @ItiTyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, there is a `null` value in your data.  Try:

```
If Isnull({Report name.InvCustLangCode}) Then
  "Debiteur"
Else
  select {Report name.InvCustLangCode} 
  case "NL" : "Debiteur nr."
  case "UK" : "Debtor nr." 
  case "DE" : "Debitor nr." 
  default: "Debiteur" -- zero-length string
```

** edit **

This formula should work in any section.  If you are not seeing the correct value, something else is occurring.

Comment: That works, but these Fields are in the Page Footer. Do you know a way to get that data availible for the Page Footer? that way when a german company gets their Invoice it would work in their native tongue

Comment: Shouldn't the select choose default when the  value for `{Report name.InvCustLangCode}` is `null`? @craig

Comment: @CasNouwens, in CR, a `null` value does not equate to the default, unless you have enabled convert null values to their defaults in the report's settings.  You should always test for null values in CR before anything else.

Comment: ok, thanks man i will keep that in mind for the rest of this project.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of the field you used to display then text in the report.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can do that? Because in the preview I have tried dragging the corners of the frame to a ridiculous size and the text still isn't in it...

Comment: Not in preview but do it in the tool and then view the preview

Comment: nope, I changed it in the "Design view" with _rmb > size and position_ it still doesn't show the text it is supposed to show